# Robot: Change timestamps in log/report files

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I am writing a C# app that runs some tests and logs test results into a text file.

I want to use Robot for just generating the html output files from my existing log files. These files contain all the information that needs to be displayed (test cases IDs, descriptions, results, timestamps, etc).

So, the plan is making Robot extract the information from the logs, including timestamps, and use those to overwrite the timestamps Robot generates. Or maybe let Robot to generate the log/report with its own timestamps and then modify the log/report.

I tried to identify timestamps in the html files after executing Robot, but it seems not to be as simple as search/replace string...

Any input/ suggestion would be really appreciated.

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robot creates an output file in XML format, and from there it generates the log and report files. You can write code to modify this xml file (which has a very simple structure), and then use robot to regenerate the log and report files.